# WPF Telerik ScatterPointSeries RenderMode deprecated

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radchart

A Telerik RadChartView is being assigned an `AnalysisChartScatterPointSeries`, where the `RenderMode` property of which was formerly being set to `SeriesRenderMode.Light`.

This property has been marked **obsolete** and, upon removing the assignment from the code, the performance for the chart has become really poor for larger data sets.

The property is marked (in the metadata) as

- "*This property is obsolete and will be removed. Use* `RenderOptions`
  *property instead.*"

But on examining this property, it has type `ChartRenderOptions`, which is an empty, abstract class.

What should I instantiate, to assign to RenderOptions, such that the performance issue can be reverted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assigned the RenderOptions property as follows:

```
RenderOptions = new XamlRenderOptions() { DefaultVisualsRenderMode = DefaultVisualsRenderMode.Batch }
```

The documentation here:
[XAML Rendering](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radchartview-features-rendering.html) helped me.